Read multiple frames in demuxer
I use FFmpeg.AutoGen. This is C# wrapper of ffmpeg (7.0) C++ library for reading mediafiles and generate stream of frames for other application.
I want get n frames and hold pointers in memory indefinitely.
However, I am completely confused trying to figure out which API is deprecated and how I can tell ffmpeg to hold the pointers in memory until I tell it to.
I don't want to copy the frame after receiving it if I can avoid it.
I tried many ways.
My last attempt was to receive the frames using ffmpeg.avcodec_send_packet(), ffmpeg.av_read_frame() and ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame() functions as it is specified in the current manual.
My code fragment for reading frames:
using Core.Backends.FFmpeg.Helpers;
using Core.Backends.FFmpeg.UnsafeWrappers;
using Core.Enums;
using Core.Interfaces;
using FFmpeg.AutoGen.Abstractions;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Core.Backends.FFmpeg.Internal;

internal class Video : IVideo
{
  private readonly AVFormatHandler p_format;
  private readonly AVCodecHandler p_codec;
  private readonly AVPacketWrapper p_packet;
  private readonly FramesPool p_framesPool;
  private readonly FramesPool p_framesBufferPool;
  private bool p_disposedValue;

  public Video(VideoMetadata _videoMetadata, AVFormatHandler _format, AVCodecHandler _codec, int _bufferizedFramesCount = 1)
  {
    Duration = _videoMetadata.Duration;
    FrameRate = _videoMetadata.FrameRate;
    FrameSize = _videoMetadata.FrameSize;
    PixelFormat = _videoMetadata.PixelFormat;
    SelectedStreamID = _videoMetadata.SelectedStreamID;
    p_format = _format;
    p_codec = _codec;
    p_packet = new AVPacketWrapper();
    var frame = new AVFrameWrapper(p_format, p_packet);
    p_framesPool = new(frame, _bufferizedFramesCount);
    p_framesBufferPool = new(frame, _bufferizedFramesCount);
  }

  /// <inheritdoc/>
  public long Duration { get; init; }

  /// <inheritdoc/>
  public (int num, int den) FrameRate { get; init; }

  /// <inheritdoc/>
  public Size FrameSize { get; init; }

  /// <inheritdoc/>
  public PixelFormat PixelFormat { get; init; }

  private int SelectedStreamID { get; init; }

  private unsafe int SendPacket(AVPacketWrapper? _packet)
  {
    if (_packet == null)
      return ffmpeg.avcodec_send_packet(p_codec.AVCodecContextPointer, null);

    return ffmpeg.avcodec_send_packet(p_codec.AVCodecContextPointer, _packet.AVPacketPointer);
  }

  private unsafe bool IsSelectedStream(AVPacketWrapper _packet)
  {
    return _packet.AVPacketPointer->stream_index == SelectedStreamID;
  }

  private unsafe int ReadFrame(AVPacketWrapper _packet)
  {
    return ffmpeg.av_read_frame(p_format.AVFormatPointer, _packet.AVPacketPointer);
  }

  private static unsafe void UnrefPacket(AVPacketWrapper _packet) => ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(_packet.AVPacketPointer);

  private IEnumerable<int> ReadToSelectedStream(AVPacketWrapper _packet)
  {
    do
    {
      UnrefPacket(p_packet);
      yield return ReadFrame(_packet);
    } while (!IsSelectedStream(_packet));
  }

  private unsafe void FlushBuffers() => ffmpeg.avcodec_flush_buffers(p_codec.AVCodecContextPointer);

  private IEnumerable<AVPacketWrapper> GetNextPacketPrivate()
  {
    try
    {
      while (true)
      {
        foreach (int errorCodeRead in ReadToSelectedStream(p_packet))
        {
          if (errorCodeRead == ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF)
            break;

          errorCodeRead.ThrowInvalidOperationExceptionIfError();
        }

        int errorCodeSend = SendPacket(p_packet);

        if (errorCodeSend == ffmpeg.AVERROR(ffmpeg.EAGAIN))
        {
          yield return p_packet;
          continue;
        }

        if (errorCodeSend == ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF)
        {
          yield return p_packet;
          break;
        }

        errorCodeSend.ThrowInvalidOperationExceptionIfError();

        yield return p_packet;
      }

      // Last iteration special case handling
      int errorCodeSendLast = SendPacket(null);

      if (errorCodeSendLast != ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF)
        errorCodeSendLast.ThrowInvalidOperationExceptionIfError();

      yield return p_packet;
    }
    finally
    {
      UnrefPacket(p_packet);
      FlushBuffers();
    }
  }

  private unsafe int ReceiveFrame(AVFrameWrapper _frame)
  {
    return ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame(p_codec.AVCodecContextPointer, _frame.AVFramePointer);
  }

  private unsafe AVFrameWrapper HWFrameCopyIfRequired(AVCodecHandler _codec, AVFrameWrapper _frame, AVFrameWrapper _buffer)
  {
    if (_codec.AVCodecContextPointer->hw_device_ctx != null)
    {
      int errorCode = ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(_buffer.AVFramePointer, _frame.AVFramePointer, flags: 0);
      errorCode.ThrowInvalidOperationExceptionIfError();
      return _buffer;
    }

    return _frame;
  }

  private IEnumerable<IFrame> GetNextFramePrivate(AVFrameWrapper _fresh_frame, AVFrameWrapper _fresh_frameBuffer)
  {
    int readCode;

    while (true)
    {
      readCode = ReceiveFrame(_fresh_frame);

      if (readCode == ffmpeg.AVERROR(ffmpeg.EAGAIN) || readCode == ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF)
        yield break;

      readCode.ThrowInvalidOperationExceptionIfError();
      
      yield return HWFrameCopyIfRequired(p_codec, _fresh_frame, _fresh_frameBuffer);
    }
  }

  private static void RefreshFrames
  (
    IEnumerator<AVFrameWrapper> _framesEnumerator,
    IEnumerator<AVFrameWrapper> _framesBufferEnumerator,
    out AVFrameWrapper _frame,
    out AVFrameWrapper _frameBuffer
  )
  {
    // Catch fresh frame from pool
    Debug.Assert(_framesEnumerator.MoveNext(), "Пул фреймов никогда не должен завершать предоставление фреймов.");
    _frame = _framesEnumerator.Current;

    // Catch fresh frame buffer from pool
    Debug.Assert(_framesBufferEnumerator.MoveNext(), "Пул фреймов никогда не должен завершать предоставление фреймов.");
    _frameBuffer = _framesBufferEnumerator.Current;
  }

  /// <inheritdoc/>
  public IEnumerable<IFrame> GetNextFrame()
  {
    IEnumerator<AVFrameWrapper> framesEnumerator = p_framesPool.GetNextFrame().GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<AVFrameWrapper> framesBufferEnumerator = p_framesBufferPool.GetNextFrame().GetEnumerator();
    RefreshFrames(framesEnumerator, framesBufferEnumerator, out AVFrameWrapper fresh_frame, out AVFrameWrapper fresh_frameBuffer);
    foreach (var packet in GetNextPacketPrivate())
      foreach (var frame in GetNextFramePrivate(fresh_frame, fresh_frameBuffer))
      {
        yield return frame;
        RefreshFrames(framesEnumerator, framesBufferEnumerator, out fresh_frame, out fresh_frameBuffer);
      }
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (!p_disposedValue)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
      }

      p_packet.Dispose();
      p_framesPool.Flush();
      p_framesBufferPool.Flush();

      p_disposedValue = true;
    }
  }

  ~Video()
  {
    Dispose(disposing: false);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }
}

My FramesPool class:
using Core.Backends.FFmpeg.UnsafeWrappers;
using FFmpeg.AutoGen.Abstractions;

namespace Core.Backends.FFmpeg.Internal;

internal class FramesPool
{
  private readonly AVFrameWrapper p_frameWrapper;
  private readonly Queue<AVFrameWrapper> p_frames;
  private readonly int p_count;

  public FramesPool(AVFrameWrapper _initframeWrapper, int _count = 1)
  {
    p_frameWrapper = _initframeWrapper;
    p_frames = new(_count);
    p_frames.Enqueue(p_frameWrapper);
    p_count = _count;
  }

  private static unsafe void UnrefFrame(AVFrameWrapper _frame) => ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(_frame.AVFramePointer);

  public IEnumerable<AVFrameWrapper> GetNextFrame()
  {
    // First frame case
    UnrefFrame(p_frameWrapper);
    yield return p_frameWrapper;

    while (true)
    {
      if (p_frames.Count < p_count)
      {
        var new_frame = p_frameWrapper.Clone();
        p_frames.Enqueue(new_frame);
        yield return new_frame;
      }
      else
      {
        var frame = p_frames.Dequeue();
        UnrefFrame(frame);
        yield return frame;
        p_frames.Enqueue(frame);
      }
    }
  }

  public void Flush()
  {
    foreach(var frame in p_frames)
    {
      UnrefFrame(frame);
      frame.Dispose();
    }

    p_frames.Clear();
  }
}

Additional calls, among others:
ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context();
ffmpeg.avformat_open_input(pptr, p_filePath, null, null);
ffmpeg.av_hwdevice_ctx_create(&p_avCodecHandler!.AVCodecContextPointer->hw_device_ctx, strongDevice, null, null, 0);
ffmpeg.av_find_best_stream(/*args*/);
ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(p_avCodec);
ffmpeg.avcodec_parameters_to_context(/*args*/);
ffmpeg.avcodec_open2(/*args*/);

Function ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(_buffer.AVFramePointer, _frame.AVFramePointer, flags: 0); returns "-22" (message: "Invalid argument")
Please, help me)

Remember that ffmpeg doesn't allocate your frames.  It decodes the frames into YOUR memory.  If you want to keep every new frame, you need to keep allocating new empty frames.  That won't last long, of course; you'll run out of memory.

@TimRoberts Did I understand you correctly?
I have to allocate several AVFrames for my task?
For example, 10 AVFrame for n=10.
This already happens in FramePool, namely in AVFrameWrapper.Clone(). I use ffmpeg.av_frame_clone(p_frame) inside. Docs: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/7.0/group__lavu__frame.html#ga46d6d32f6482a3e9c19203db5877105b

Maybe I should use something instead of av_frame_clone()? To reference different memory

Indeed, as Tim Roberts pointed out in comments, the problem was that av_frame_clone does not allocate new memory. Instead, I create a completely new frame or call av_frame_unref on the old frames. This solved my problem.
